# Placing text over images

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider, owl-carousel

I am using [owl-carousel](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/) to make a `slider` for a website. I could easily make a slider using the following code :

```
<div id="owl-slider" class="owl-carousel"> 
                <div> <img src="images/1.jpg" /> </div>
                <div> <img src="images/2.jpg" /> </div>
                <div> <img src="images/3.jpg" /> </div>
                <div> <img src="images/4.jpg" /> </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
                $("#owl-slider").owlCarousel({
                    items : 1,
                    autoPlay : true,
                    slideSpeed : 200,
                    stopOnHover : true,
                    navigation : false
                })

                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $("#owl-slider").owlCarousel();

                }); 
</script>
```

I also want to place some text on the images in the slider. Unique text for each image. How can I do this with owl-carousel ?

Comment: please give your fiddle

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please check [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZVXa3/) here

```
<div id="owl-slider" class="owl-carousel"> 
<div> <div class="textoverlay"><h1>Text 1</h1><p>Some text bla bla bla</p></div><img src="http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/assets/owl1.jpg" /></div>
            <div> <h2>Text 2</h2><img src="http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/assets/owl6.jpg" /> </div>
            <div><h2>Text 3</h2> <img src="http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/assets/owl8.jpg" /> </div>
            <div> <h2>Text 4</h2><img src="http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/assets/owl3.jpg" /> </div>
```

CSS

```
.owl-carousel div h2, .owl-carousel div .textoverlay{
    position:absolute;
    color:#FFF;
   font-size:12px;
   display:block;
}
```

I check owl-carousel  using DIV to define the thumb scroll, it mean you can easy to customize it. (Link removed due to SPAM)

Hope that help you :)

Comment: your link heve virus... [CAUTION]

Comment: The demo doesn't work. Any chance to have a working example?